# How to get double value from "declare-styleable"

Tags: android, double, declare-styleable

How to get **double value** from **declare-styleable**?

attributes.xml

```
<declare-styleable name="MeterView">
    <attr name="volume" format="double"/> // Can't resolved format
</declare-styleable>
```

Assign double value to meterView

```
<com.test.example.MeterView
    android:id="@+id/meter1"
    android:layout_width="295dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    app:volume="123456789.01"/>
```

Calling attributes.xml

```
Double volume = a.getDouble(R.styleable.MeterView_volume); // Can't resolved getDouble
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use **float** instead of double in your attributes.xml file. double is not allowed.

```
<declare-styleable name="MeterView">
        <attr name="volume" format="float"/> 
</declare-styleable>

a.getFloat(R.styleable.MeterView_volume);
```

**or** use string and convert String to double in runtime.

```
<declare-styleable name="MeterView">
            <attr name="volume" format="string"/> 
 </declare-styleable>

double d= Double.parseDouble(a.getString(R.styleable.MeterView_volume));
```